# ArrayList returning same values

Tags: java, rest, arraylist

I have this code in EmployeeListItem.java.
`auditList` has 3 list items. I want to iterate over this list and add the result to another list which I want to use in another method. But the list prints the same value (latest value from the list).

```
   public List<EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO> auditListItems(List<EmployeeAuditListItem> auditList) {
   EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO auditResponse = new EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO();
   List<EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO> responseList = new ArrayList<>();

   for (EmployeeAuditListItem items : auditList) {
     auditResponse.Employee_AUDIT_ID = items.getEmployeeAuditId();
     auditResponse.Employee_ID = items.getEmployeeId();

     System.out.println("ID: " + auditResponse.Employee_AUDIT_ID); //prints -> ID: 1, ID: 2, ID: 3 

     responseList.add(auditResponse);
   }

  //To verify responseList printing
    for (EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO items : responseList) {
     System.out.println("ID :" + items.AUDIT_TYPE_DESC); //prints the same value-> ID: 1, ID: 1, ID: 1
   }
   return responseList;
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you are creating only one auditResponse  object .put it inside the loop

Comment: @MadhawaPriyashantha thanks! that worked.
silly mistake. New to Programming :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `auditResponse`  Object. You should create a new object and then add that object into responseList list.

```
  public List<EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO> auditListItems(List<EmployeeAuditListItem> auditList) {
   List<EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO> responseList = new ArrayList<>();

   for (EmployeeAuditListItem items : auditList) {
   EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO auditResponse = new EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO();// create new object for auditResponse
     auditResponse.Employee_AUDIT_ID = items.getEmployeeAuditId();
     auditResponse.Employee_ID = items.getEmployeeId();

     System.out.println("ID: " + auditResponse.Employee_AUDIT_ID); //prints -> ID: 1, ID: 2, ID: 3 

     responseList.add(auditResponse);
   }

  //To verify responseList printing
    for (EmployeeAuditListItemResponseVO items : responseList) {
     System.out.println("ID :" + items.AUDIT_TYPE_DESC); //prints the same value-> ID: 1, ID: 1, ID: 1
   }
   return responseList;
```